# Simple injector: Get root of the graph

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, tree, simple-injector

For instance I have following object graph:

```
new Root(
   new Branch(),
   new BranchWithLeafs(
      new Leaf()
   )
);
```

Let's take `Leaf` I can determine what the parent of `Leaf` using [context dependent injection](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ContextDependentExtensions&referringTitle=Advanced-scenarios) but how I can get `Root`?

Comment: By using context dependent injection with `Branch` and `BranchWithLeafs`?  If it works with `Leaf`, then it ought to work with the higher levels.

Comment: @Robert that is very simplified example. In my scenario the number of nodes and their lifecycle varies..

Comment: Yes, but the mechanism shouldn't.  Basically, it's going to be a recursive operation, right?  If it's [turtles all the way down](http://transversalinflections.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/turtles-all-the-way-down.png), you should be able to walk the tree all the way back to the root.

Comment: This is in fact quite complicated to do. Can you update your question to explain what you're trying to achieve. There might be another (or better) way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The reason this is rather complicated to do in this case is because the `RegisterWithContext` extension methods use a callback delegate that allows changing the expression tree of the parent before it gets compiled, but you can't go to the parent's parent with this technique, since the parent can be a singleton (an `Expression.Constant`). In other words, at the time the parent's parent gets intercepted, its child is already an `Expression.Constant` (its expression tree is already compiled and executed) and can't be changed. You can do this as long as the whole graph is transient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RegisterWithContext` extension method uses the `ExpressionBuilding` event on the background and intercepts the `Expression` object of the `Leaf`'s parent and changes the invocation of the `Leaf`'s delegate so that the `DependencyContext` is passed in.

It's quite easy to extend the code to allow the parent's parent (`Root` in your case) to be intercepted as well, but unfortunately this breaks rather quickly when you register your services with a lifestyle that is longer than `Transient`. This is caused by the optimizations that Simple Injector does under the cover. For instance, when you register `Branch` as singleton, its value gets created before the `Root` Expression gets created, which means that at that point there is no Expression tree that can be changed once the `Root` gets built. So in that case the `Root` simply depends on a `Expression.Constant` that holds a reference to the `Branch` instance and you lose the ability to change the creation of the `Leaf`. I think this is one of the few scenarios where these optimizations that Simple Injector does work against you.

Here is an altered version of the `RegisterWithContext` extension method that allows working with 'turtles all the way down', but keep in mind that the chain gets truncated once you register anything in the tree with a different lifestyle than `Transient`:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("DependencyContext (ServiceType: {ServiceType}, " + 
    "ImplementationType: {ImplementationType})")]
public class DependencyContext {
    internal static readonly DependencyContext Root = 
        new DependencyContext();

    internal DependencyContext(Type serviceType, 
        Type implementationType, DependencyContext parent)
    {
        this.ServiceType = serviceType;
        this.ImplementationType = implementationType;
        this.Parent = parent;
    }

    private DependencyContext() { }

    // There's now a Parent property!
    public DependencyContext Parent { get; private set; }
    public Type ServiceType { get; private set; }
    public Type ImplementationType { get; private set; }
}

public static class ContextDependentExtensions {
    public static void RegisterWithContext<TService>(
        this Container container,
        Func<DependencyContext, TService> contextBasedFactory)
        where TService : class {
        if (contextBasedFactory == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("contextBasedFactory");
        }

        Func<TService> rootFactory = 
            () => contextBasedFactory(DependencyContext.Root);

        container.Register<TService>(rootFactory, Lifestyle.Transient);

        // Allow the Func<DependencyContext, TService> to be 
        // injected into parent types.
        container.ExpressionBuilding += (sender, e) => {
            if (e.RegisteredServiceType != typeof(TService)) {
                var rewriter = new DependencyContextRewriter {
                    ServiceType = e.RegisteredServiceType,
                    ContextBasedFactory = contextBasedFactory,
                    RootFactory = rootFactory,
                    Expression = e.Expression
                };

                e.Expression = rewriter.Visit(e.Expression);
            }
        };
    }

    private sealed class DependencyContextRewriter : ExpressionVisitor {
        internal Type ServiceType { get; set; }
        internal object ContextBasedFactory { get; set; }
        internal object RootFactory { get; set; }
        internal Expression Expression { get; set; }

        internal Type ImplementationType
        {
            get {
                var expression = this.Expression as NewExpression;

                if (expression != null) {
                    return expression.Constructor.DeclaringType;
                }

                return this.ServiceType;
            }
        }

        protected override Expression VisitInvocation(InvocationExpression node) {
            var context = GetContextFromNode(node);

            if (context == null) {
                return base.VisitInvocation(node);
            }

            return Expression.Invoke(
                Expression.Constant(this.ContextBasedFactory),
                Expression.Constant(
                    new DependencyContext(
                        this.ServiceType,
                        this.ImplementationType,
                        context)));
        }

        private DependencyContext GetContextFromNode(InvocationExpression node) {
            var constant = node.Expression as ConstantExpression;

            if (constant != null) {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(constant.Value, this.RootFactory)) {
                    return DependencyContext.Root;
                }

                if (object.ReferenceEquals(constant.Value, this.ContextBasedFactory)) {
                    var arg = (ConstantExpression)node.Arguments[0];
                    return (DependencyContext)(arg.Value);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Steven that is very comprehensive answer, although it doesn't solve my issue but that answers my question.

Comment: @Vladimirs: Yes, I'm sorry. The real answer is that you can't walk the parent hierarchy using Context Based Injection with Simple Injector. I like to give you some specific guidance, but to be able to do that I need to have a better understanding of the actual application structure and the types; your question is currently too abstract to say anything useful about that.

Comment: I already understood that I was too abstract and every little matters, therefore I created [more detailed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323463/simple-injector-different-dbcontext-for-selected-controllers)