# Simple Injector: Different DbContext for selected controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I am trying to separate reads/writes in my MVC application. I am using Simple Injector as Ioc and I have following structure:

```
new Service(
  new Repository(
     new UnitOfWork(
        new DbContext())))
```

So `UnitOfWork` registered per web request all the rest `Transient`.

So idea was to create separate read-only controllers and make a registration of `DbContext` to supply a different connection if controller is read-only. And that could be achievable with [improved RegisterWithContext extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22310316/simple-injector-get-root-of-the-graph/22320376?noredirect=1#22320376) BUT it will not work in my case because not all graph nodes are `Transient`.

Is there any way (more elegant than register each Repository with *improved RegisterWithContext extension* where need to supply another read-only `UnitOfWork` and manually resolve all other arguments that passed into `Repository`) how the described scenario can be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the choice is based on the type of controller, you can make the descision in a custom `IControllerFactory`. For instance:

```
public class ConnectionSelector {
    public bool AsReadOnly { get; set; }
}

private class ReadOnlySwitchControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory {
    private readonly Container container;

    public ReadOnlySwitchControllerFactory(Container container) {
        this.container = container;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, 
        Type controllerType) {
        var selector = this.container.GetInstance<ConnectionSelector>();

        selector.AsReadOnly = 
            typeof(IReadOnlyController).IsAssignableFrom(controllerType);

        return base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType);
    }
}
```

You can register this as follows:

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ConnectionSelector>();

container.RegisterPerWebRequest<DbContext>(() => new DbContext(
    container.GetInstance<ConnectionSelector>().AsReadOnly 
        ? "ReadOnlyConnection" 
        : "NormalConnection"));

container.RegisterSingle<IControllerFactory>(
    new ReadOnlySwitchControllerFactory(container));
```

Comment: Thank you, so sophisticated approach - exactly what I needed.

Comment: As alternative, you can also add abstraction to your application (like `IConnectionSelector`) and inject it into your `DbContext`.